# how to search through the directory structure and get the .sln file name using MSBuild

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, msbuild, continuous-integration, msbuild-task

I am setting up a build environment for few projects. Each project has more than one solution. I am in need of building all the solutions that will fall in different folders within a root directory. The lever of folder in with the solution files resides from the root directory can vary. That is the solutions file can be embedded with a folder which in turn can be with in another folder and so forth. How can I to search through the root directory structure and get the list of all the solutions (.sln) file name and its path using MSBuild so that I can build these solutions?

Similarly I would have to search for and get the list of all the dll and exe generated from the build so that I can run static code analysis on them. I am looking for a way that I can search and get the list of assemblies and their file path.

Comment: Perhaps it worth to keep all solution files in the same folder?

Comment: If I were to create those projects, I would defiantly structure the solutions to be in one folder. Unfortunately I don’t have that luxury.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will find and report all solution files below the folder of the file this is placed in:

```
<Target Name="FindSolutions">
   <ItemGroup>
      <SolutionFile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\**\*.sln" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <Message Text="Found '%(SolutionFile.Identity)'" />
</Target>
```

The key is the `**` which matches all folders recursively.

Comment: Thanks Brain, I thought \**\ would drill in one folder below the root ie from the about example a folder below $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory) .What if the solution file is buried in more deep like \..\..\..\.sln or \.\.\.\.\.sln .How would I deal with this situation?